# Kendo UI Mobile not working on Phonegap Emulator

Tags: javascript, cordova, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I want to use Phonegap emulator to test an App which uses Kendo UI Mobile. Kendo UI is initialized when I test it on real devices ,Still Geolocation onSuccess method is never called, but on Phonegap Emulator I can not even see Kendo Ui being initialized. Please help me  to run this App

```
var MYAPP = MYAPP || {};
MYAPP.onSuccess = (function(position)
{
    var myLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    map  = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: myLocation,
    zoom: 15
});

});


MYAPP.onError = (function(error)
 {
  alert("error initializing map")

});


MYAPP.run = (function() {
// create the Kendo UI Mobile application
   alert("kendo initialized");
   MYAPP.app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, { transition: "slide" });
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(MYAPP.onSuccess, MYAPP.onError);

});


MYAPP.show = (function() {
  $(document.body).show();
});


   (function() {
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Browzr') > -1) {
    // blackberry
    setTimeout(MYAPP.run, 250)
} else {
    // attach to deviceready event, which is fired when phonegap is all good to go.
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', MYAPP.run, false);
      alert("hello")
}
})();
```

Comment: You dont really have to initialize Kendo on deviceready event. You can write Kendo init code just above </body> tag without the document.ready event